# Taking the modulus of 2 arrays

Tags: algorithms, arrays, modular-arithmetic

I'm putting together a primality tester for large numbers. When the numbers were smaller things were more straightforwards. I got refined it to a point where I could quickly test any number within the range of long long ints. I wanted to be able to test larger numbers. I've gotten it to read the numbers in as strings then convert to an array. I now have the issue of not knowing how to perform mod on arrays. (int*)mod(int) isn't too bad but (int*)mod(int*) is more complicated.

In short:

1. Is there a relationship between n%c and n%a,n%b where a+b=c
2. How do you take the mod of 2 sums where either sum would give you overload.

Comment: The description part of your question is pure implementation problem, which is not clearly stated and off-topic here. We prefer to state one question per post and also to make some research prior to asking. 1) looks like pure math, 2) part is unclear - how do you store the number if it causes overload? If this is causing all the trouble, it is unfortunatelly off-topic here because it asks about implementation details (might be on-topic on [SO]).

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test.

Answer (score 1):

Representing integers that are larger than the machine integer size by an array of digits is the standard way to do it, and it's usually called *bignum*, or more formally [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum).

Division on bignums is not simple. There's no shortcut: it isn't like with addition and subtraction where you can make a single loop that goes over both arrays. You can use the long division method you learned in primary school. There are more complex methods that have better performance in general; the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm) has a good overview.

There is no useful relationship between $n \bmod (a+b)$ and $n \bmod a$ and $n \bmod b$. I don't see where this would come up anyway. (On the other hand, $(a+b) \bmod p$ is either $(a \bmod p) + (b \bmod p)$ or $(a \bmod p) + (b \bmod p) - p$ depending on whether the sum overflows $p$).

When computing with numbers modulo $n$, always reduce modulo $n$ after each operation, to avoid having numbers grow too large. During one operation, it's usually useful to allow one more digit, to accumulate carries on partial results.

Note that [primality testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality#Testing_primality_and_integer_factorization) is rarely done on large numbers, because it gets extremely slow. In cryptography, approximate algorithms are used, that have a small probability of accepting a composite number as prime (but if the algorithm says “prime”, then the number may not be prime, but it's “difficult” to factor).